# Is Subversion's 'Lazy Copy' still lazy when overwriting a previously deleted file?

Tags: svn, externals

Is Subversion's 'Lazy Copy' still lazy when overwriting a previously deleted file?

I store my externals in a separate folder for each version: i.e say for dojo I'd have:

```
 webroot\
  scripts\
   dojo-v-1.0.0\
   dojo-v-1.1.0\
```

etc.
By doing this, for me at least, I feel it makes it easier to switch over to a new version.

By only adding each new version i am not really giving svn the history it needs to do lazy copies. So one tactic I have used is to

- svn copy over the old version over to
  where the new one will be
- then svn
  delete that whole folder
- then unpack my newer version into that place
- then svn add them

The idea is to avoid having a massive amount of duplicated data in my repo.

I hope svn is looking at the new files and saying,

"hey, i already had this once, copied, then deleted...so i am going to be lazy and only store the changes".

That was my theory - but does that happen in practice?

p.s. Yes I know an alternative is to set the 'externals properties on the folder' - but that's another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the chapter ["vendor branches"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html#svn.advanced.vendorbr.general) in subversion book, because this is exactly what they are about.

To answer your question:

**No, subversion will not use a lazy copy on new added files** in your described scenario.

If you want to avoid this, use **load_dirs.pl** (which is also described in vendor branches chapter)